# Access to page fragment besides within the ready method

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

When I'm in the ready method for a WinJS page I have access to the page element (the fragment) because it's passed in as the element parameter. Is there a way to access this outside the ready method? I know I can save it to a higher scoped variable from within the ready method and then it's available, but I wonder if that's unnecessary.

Comment: "*it's passed in as the element parameter*" - How does this work? Could you explain?

Comment: The ready method signature for a WinJS page is `ready(element, options)` so I'm just pointing out that I have access to the `element` object _inside_ the ready method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is stored on the page instance -- you can access this through the .element property.

This assumes that you used the Page class to define your page, and the constructor for the page class takes care of this for you, before it calls .ready.

Comment: Thanks. Here's what I ended up with: `document.getElementById("contenthost").winControl._element`. That works, but I decided to actually do it differently. I store the element from the ready method and make it available to the rest of the page's module (the immediate function).

Comment: Are you saying the .element property is null/undefined? The code for the page constructor actually saves it off; it should be available.

Comment: The element property of what? this.element? window.element?

Comment: this.element; the ready function should be called in the context of the page control instance